# Is there a 'internal' endpoint we should be using to connect between RDS/EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Provided that EC2 and RDS are on the same VPC, is there an internal endpoint we need to use to speed up data exchange between the two?

Similar to how if MySQL + Apache are on 1 server we would connect using 'localhost' (avoiding TCP/IP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EC2 and RDS are not running on the same server, so `localhost` would not work. A VPC is still a network, and you would still use TCP inside that network to connect from one server to the other.

Comment: So it would just need to go through the endpoint RDS provides, no way around it, it will always be over TCP/IP... Is it able to determine that both are in the same VPC so the exchange is quicker? Thanks

Comment: Yes it has to go through the endpoint, no way around it, and yes it will always be over TCP/IP because it is communication between two computers on a TCP/IP network. Within the VPC the endpoint address should resolve to an internal IP address that is within your VPC's CIDR block. You can test this easily from the EC2 server using something like `ping` or `traceroute`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the RDS instance in the same VPC as your other EC2 and lambda resources, you could directly connect with the **ENI elastic network interface**, by specifying the ingress security group rule in RDS DB from the EC2 Security group. Other ways of authentication that you get at the time of database instance provisioning are

[image]
[image]

Comment: ENI's are connected to EC2 by default over eth0, and my RDS is on the same VPC, so what is the endpoint that needs to be used? The solution seems to answer a quicker way to authenticate rather than data IO. We are re not using Lambda.